# Prestashop Module not able to install

Tags: module, prestashop-1.6

I installed free supercheckout plugin before. It worked flawlessly. Now I purchased their plugin. Disabled that old free plugin. unsinstalled it and deleted it. Now when i am installing the paid plugin Its giving me this error:

The following module(s) could not be installed properly:
supercheckout :
.

This is the plugin that i bought:
https://www.knowband.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=86

Comment: enable error in config/defines.inc.php  and try to install again, it ll show you the error during the install

Comment: its gives me this error:

Unknown error on line 280 in file /home/shoprayzonline/public_html/gokulan/modules/googleshopping/lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php
[8192] Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Crypt_RSA has a deprecated constructor

Comment: Unknown error on line 82 in file /home/shoprayzonline/public_html/gokulan/modules/googleshopping/lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Hash.php
[8192] Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Crypt_Hash has a deprecated constructor

Unknown error on line 176 in file /home/shoprayzonline/public_html/gokulan/modules/googleshopping/lib/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php
[8192] Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Math_BigInteger has a deprecated constructor

Comment: I removed the google shopping module properly and still its showing me error

Comment: how can you get an error on a file that you deleted ? be sure the file is well deleted, the errors must change if the module did not install

Comment: also , install the same version prestashop in local without any addons and try to install the module on it please and let me know if it worked

Comment: i meant i am still getting the not installed error.. those googleshopp errors are gone now

Comment: i meant i am still getting the not installed error.. those googleshopp errors are gone now

Comment: wait lemme add prestashop in local ..

Comment: nop, i installed the module on a new setup with same version of prestashop . its still giving me same error

Comment: if on fresh prestashop you get an error also, try to contact them support, i hope they can help you